# 15.04: rsync connection refused

Tags: 15.04, rsync

I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 this weekend. Now, rsync won't play nice anymore:

When I try to run this:

```
beheer@boson:~ $ rsync -Wvvqaz --log-file=rs.txt --delete-excluded --delete --no-g --password-file=/home/beheer/rsync.local.pwd --exclude=lost+found /home  rsync://boson.local/boson-backup/boson/
```

I get:

```
rsync: failed to connect to boson.local (10.0.1.220): Connection refused (111)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(128) [sender=3.1.1]
```

the log-file contains:

```
2015/05/25 19:00:54 [15163] opening tcp connection to boson.local port 873
2015/05/25 19:00:54 [15163] rsync: failed to connect to boson.local (10.0.1.220): Connection refused (111)
2015/05/25 19:00:54 [15163] rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(128) [sender=3.1.1]
```

This is an attempt at a local backup. But, trying to do something similar from an external (Debian) server returns the exact same error.

```
$ systemctl |grep ufw
  ufw.service                 loaded active exited    Uncomplicated firewall

$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any suggestions what else I could check or what could be wrong?

EDIT: Using rsync via ssh as suggested in the comments below gives the same error.

EDIT2: updated firewall (`ufw`) status and added `iptables` state.

EDIT3: Shouldn't there be an `rsyncd` daemon running?

```
$ ps aux |grep rsync
beheer    8559  0.0  0.0   9492  2176 pts/0    S+   10:23   0:00 grep --color=auto rsync
```

`systemctl` also doesn't show any `rsync` service. No mention on Google that this is needed or how to create it.

Comment: I've never used rsync with an actual rsync server.  Any reason you're not tunneling over ssh? (I suppose rsync would be faster since it skips the encryption, but just curious)

Comment: This is all local traffic. Would, using `ssh`, help solve my problem or just add an extra layer of complexity?

Comment: well, assuming you have ssh working and setup.  Try something along these lines:
rsync -avP  --log-file=rs.txt --delete-excluded --delete --no-g --exclude=lost+found /home   user@boson.local:/boson-backup/boson/

that should be equivalent.  You can also play around with -z (compression) and --compress-level=NUM  (ie.  balance between CPU usage and badwidth).  I'm not sure if this would be a solution.. but like I said.. I've never had the need to setup an rsync server since ssh is just always available in all my env.  Worth giving it a go and see if it works. (assuming ssh is open)

Comment: @csgeek : This has the added problem that I need to enter a password, so I can't run this from a script. It then complains that it can't `mkdir /boson-backup/boson`. But boson-backup` is a module, it shouldn't be created. :-\

Comment: ssh-keygen  (generate a password less key).  ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@host, then it should work w/o a password and be just as secure.  If you really want to give your crypto key a pass phrase you can play around with ssh-agent and such and still have your script work.

Comment: Result:  rsync: failed to connect to boson.local (10.0.1.220): Connection refused (111)     .     
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(128) [Receiver=3.1.1]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rsync.service IS installed. You just need to look very hard. ;-)

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files |grep rsync
rsync.service                          disabled
```

Since the service is disabled by default (...) you need to enable it and then start it.

```
$ sudo systemctl enable rsync.service
Synchronizing state for rsync.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d rsync defaults
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d rsync enable

$ sudo systemctl start rsync.service
```

And there you go:

```
$ systemctl |grep rsync
rsync.service                 loaded active running   fast remote file copy program daemon
```

This survives reboots. So no need to manually start the service after each boot.